WSL 1 to access shared network drives on start
How for WSL 1 to access shared network drives, and set it up only once on system start?

My network share is already mapped to a drive letter (Z:), however my WSL 1 only automatically mounts my local Windows drives (e.g., C:, D:, etc.) under /mnt/, no /mnt/z
When I access the network drive via its UNC path, e.g., cd //ServerName/SharedFolder, which works fine under cmd, my WSL 1 failed with No such file or directory

All in all I want this /mnt/z to be available each time I start WSL, and

I don't want to adding the mount command to my ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile, which would cause it to be executed every time a new shell session starts, which is not ideal.
I cannot use /etc/fstab for automounting filesystems under WSL1 either, as it does not directly rely on it.

